# Onclick of image toggle image src

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 3 menus in my page and for each menu I have 2 color of images(blue and green img).

- by default blue imgs are there
- onclick of menu it will be replaced by green img

Onclick on each menu images should be toggled accordingly. I have done it and its working fine.

HTML:

```
<div class="catSection">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4  col-xs-4">
    <img src="design.svg" id='changeImage1' ng-click="changeImage($event)">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <img src="compute.svg" id='changeImage2' ng-click="changeImage($event)">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4  col-xs-4">
    <img src="cloud.svg" id='changeImage3' ng-click="changeImage($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Client Script:

```
$scope.changeImage = function(event) {

  // $(".catSection img").removeClass("active");
  //$(event.target).addClass("active");

  if (event.target.src.split('/')[3] == 'design.svg')
    $("#" + event.target.id).attr("src", "design_open1.svg");
  else if (event.target.src.split('/')[3] == 'design_open1.svg')
    $("#" + event.target.id).attr("src", "design.svg");

  if (event.target.src.split('/')[3] == 'compute.svg')
    $("#" + event.target.id).attr("src", "compute_open.svg");
  else if (event.target.src.split('/')[3] == 'compute_open.svg')
    $("#" + event.target.id).attr("src", "compute.svg");

  if (event.target.src.split('/')[3] == 'cloud.svg')
    $("#" + event.target.id).attr("src", "public_open.svg");
  else if (event.target.src.split('/')[3] == 'public_open.svg')
    $("#" + event.target.id).attr("src", "cloud.svg");
}
```

Issue is when I click on one menu img ,rest of the menu imgs are suppose to replaced by blue which means initial position.

Its same as like a toggling active classes between list elements.

I am stuck there. Can anyone suggest some ideas please?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you use AngularJs and jQuery together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with Angular yet, but your jQuery function could look like this.
In this example I've added a `p` tag to show the sources of the images.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.catSection img').on('click', onClickCatSectionImage);

  function onClickCatSectionImage(event) {
    var targetImage = $(event.target);
    var targetSrc = targetImage.attr('src');

    // this selector is important to get the other menues too
    $('.catSection img').not(targetImage).each(function(index, element) {
      var siblingImage = $(element);
      siblingImage.attr('src', siblingImage.attr('src').replace('_open1.svg', '.svg'));
    });

    if (targetSrc.includes('._open1.svg')) {
      targetImage.attr('src', targetSrc.replace('_open1.svg', '.svg'));
    } else {
      targetImage.attr('src', targetSrc.replace('.svg', '_open1.svg'));
    }

    // this function could be deleted because is just for showing the image sources
    showImageSrc();
  }

  function showImageSrc() {
    $('.catSection img').each(function(index, element) {
      $(element).siblings('p').text($(element).attr('src'));
    });
  }

});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row catSection">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <img src="design.svg" id="changeImage1">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <img src="compute.svg" id="changeImage2">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4  col-xs-4">
    <img src="cloud.svg" id="changeImage3">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row catSection">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <img src="o_design.svg" id="changeImage4">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <img src="o_compute.svg" id="changeImage5">
    <p></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4  col-xs-4">
    <img src="o_cloud.svg" id="changeImage6">
    <p></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Your code looks fine but when I replace my image names in your code its not working properly.

Comment: @krish The code snippet here works, so the error must be somewhere in your code. Do you get any error messages in the developer console or something else? Do you see, that I've deleted the `ng-click` attribute of the images?

Comment: I did the same but blue imgs are not replaced back when I click other menus.

Comment: @krish I have edited my answer and added a second element.

Comment: Its perfect. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add two `data-` attributes to the image

1. `data-src` - store the blue image src
2. `data-srcActive` - store the green image src

Now on your `ng-click` event do these

1. Loop through each `img` which is a descendant of `catSection`
2. find the clicked image by matching the id
3. if clicked img has blue image, make it green else blue
4. else blue image
   Code

```js
$scope.changeImage = function(event) {

  var target = event.target,
    targetImg = target.src.split('/').pop();

  $('.catSection img').each(function() {
    var elm = this,
      $elm = $(elm);
    // if img is clicked image and default state
    if (elm.id === target.id && elm.src === $elm.data('src')) {
      elm.src = $elm.data('srcActive'); //active
    } else { // reset all other src to default
      elm.src = $elm.data('src'); //default
    }
  });

};
```

```html
<div class="catSection">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4  col-xs-4">
    <img data-src="design.svg" data-srcActive="design_open1.svg" src="design.svg" id='changeImage1' ng-click="changeImage($event)">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <img data-src="compute.svg" data-srcActive="compute_open.svg" src="compute.svg" id='changeImage2' ng-click="changeImage($event)">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4  col-xs-4">
    <img data-src="cloud.svg" data-srcActive="public_open.svg" src="cloud.svg" id='changeImage3' ng-click="changeImage($event)">
  </div>
</div>
```